# Could comment notification also add "Ends With" as a test?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, comments

In many cases where people have responded to me, given my moniker of "Sofware Monkey", people have chosen "@Monkey: ...", which makes sense.  Likewise, if Jeff Cho and Jeff Atwood had both commented, I might use "@Atwood: ...".

It seems like it would be very useful to do an ends-with match as well as the current starts-with match for identifying comments for notification.

Alternately, if no match is found with Starts-With, perhaps it could try again with Contains.

Comment: @ftwa - I'm waiting for "has SOUNDEX within 1 of" ;-p

Comment: Change your name to "Monkey Software". Problem solved!

Comment: They only have to type the first three letters of your username.  If the person responding to you cannot manage this task, chances are good their comment isn't worth reading.  /cynical

Comment: @Poland: What's annoying about the first-three rule is that when people misspell my name, they almost invariably do it by getting the third letter wrong (mmeyers).

Comment: @John: (@Smithers??): [grin].  If I were a Software created for Monkeys, that would make sense.

Comment: @Poll: I don't want to see people starting to type "@Sof: xxx" to direct a comment to me.

Comment: @mmyers - ha, I didn't receive notification for your comment.  @software - yeah, I'm curious to see how this all falls out.  I'm shortening the names on a case by case basis, but it's easier, faster, and less error prone to go with just the first three characters, so I expect the shorthand will win out.

Comment: @Pol: I wonder why not; is it now the first *four* letters or something? Or is it because the "Pol" wasn't followed by a space? If you get one for this, then that makes it more curious.

Comment: @mmyers - I get pol, poll, pollyanna.  Interesting.

Comment: @mmymymy - do you get this one?

Comment: @Pol: No, I don't get mmymymy. I suspect that the match must succeed up to the first non-alphabetic character.

Comment: @mmy - that's what I've been assuming.

Answer (score 1):

It still doesn't solve the *real* problem. It would be interesting if we could address Jeff as

> @wood: this is a comment.

Comment: I have to agree, it should not be difficult to make the matching much more effective.

Comment: If you think about it, "@wood" more or less correct if you say it out loud...

Comment: @meta name: Are you just figuring this out?

Comment: @Geoffrey Rich B Chetwood - No, I noticed it a while ago. It's not exactly a common topic of conversation, and never came up before now. You can give me back my two cents if you like.

Comment: Actually, this would work with an ends-with match.  Of course, @wood would match Geoffrey Chetwood too... which may not be wrong since Rich B is parodying Jeff.

Comment: It won't be an issue unless Rich B and Jeff actually talk in the same thread. Which only happens on Meta, and even then most people say @Atwood anyway so it won't be an issue.

Comment: "impersonating"

Answer (score 0):

Well... all we need is a good morphophonemic software and a training run to help our new awesome comment notifier AI.  I get the feeling that very soon, a rudimentary knowledge of english will become necessary.  Anyone want to work on such an AI?